# Is there a platform for developing a navigation app in c++?

Tags: navigation, maps

I work with 2D maps consisting of vectors and endpoints.  I would like to be able to view these in 3D, the same way my car's navigation system does it, with perspective views and rotation, to get a driver's eye view of the map as I move around it.  I am looking for a c++ library to do the hard parts.

I thought a good first step might be converting my data to csv, then finding third-party code to convert that to gpx, then looking for a library of viewing functions.  I assume another approach would be to learn OpenGL or equivalent, but that seems daunting, unless I could find some sample code showing how to do just what I need.

I'm not having much luck with the research so far.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll go there.